# Won't ripples run out in time?

Tags: ripple, ripple-transaction-fees

If there are a finite number of ripples, and ripple transaction fees get destroyed with each transaction, then wont they eventually run out?

Comment: After ~10^16 transactions, that's ten quadrillion or ten million billion. The first whole XRP has yet to be destroyed.

Comment: @DaveC you could post that as an answer, I'd say

Comment: So the the answer is Yes, but humans will probably be using something else by then, or will have become extinct or computers will have taken over etc etc. So we need not worry.

Answer (score 4):

The fee is variable over time.  As the supply dwindles, the relative value of each XRP will be higher, so the transaction fee will get lower.  They'll never really run out.

https://ripple.com/wiki/Transaction_Fee

Comment: There must become a point where the number of decimal places run out. Probably not for a long time.